# Background image not appearing HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image, stylesheet, document-body

I am new to html/css and I do not understand why my background image is not showing up. This is part of a simple test `CSS` sheet and `HTML` code for a simple site. I am trying to add a `background-image` and I have done this once and it worked and I do not know why it does not work now.

```
body{
background: url (rio.jpg); 
background-size: cover; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover; 
}
```

This is part of my css sheet. THe url works, I have used it for another trial site before. And my html is just a regular html document with a body etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing the following:

```
background-image: url(http://www.example.com/images/bck.png); // absolute path

background-image: url(rio.jpg); // relative path
```

If you are stating that the path is just rio.jpg, the image should be in the same directory as the stylesheet/where you are declaring the background.

If the image is in an image directory, you may need to go up a level as follows:

```
background-image: url(../images/rio.jpg);
```

Depends where the image file is located. You can refer to following for further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Hope this helps!

Comment: Quotes around the path are not required.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is picky about functions.

You can't have a space after 'url' and the parenthesis.

Correct:
`background: url(path/to/image.jpg);`

Incorrect:
`background: url (path/to/image.jpg);`

Here's a fiddle demonstrating:
http://jsfiddle.net/tJmmn/

Comment: Thank you, that made it work just fine! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Haha I had the same problem, make sure you have the right ".png" or ".jpg"!

After all my searching, the problem was I had a file called "bg.png", but I was typing in "bg.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I used "background" and instead of "background-image".
Secondly, make sure that the element that has the background e.g a div tag is not empty, else the background image won't show

Comment: what do you mean by 'the element that has the background should not be empty'? Please clarify. Thanks :) @TiNo

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if you are trying to give the height of the background image in %. If you give that in px it should work and if you still want to give the height in % i.e. 100%(generally) than **add this in css:
body{
`margin: 0;`
`padding: 0;`
`positive: absolute;`
`top: 0;`
`bottom: 0;`
`left: 0;`
`right: 0;`
}**

This should work as well.